# Генератор списка методов класса с описанием

Tags: php, ооп

Как можно сгенерировать список методов класса с их описанием, которые бы бралось из комментария к каждому методу? Есть ли что-то автоматическое для этих целей? В phpstorm есть возможность отобразить список методов. Но нет описания.

Comment: doxygen и еже с ним

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, оформить код в соответствии с phpdoc
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc
(Хотя бы описания функций)

А потом уже генерировать документацию с помощью doxygen или аналогов (как написал ArchDemon)